# radio bot discord using selenium to automate entering the radio website and clicking the play button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, discord.py, pydub

I wrote a code in python using the libraries: discord.py, selenium and pydub, i also tried to use youtube_dl. Basically the logic is to transfer the audio from the website to the discord bot in the app's voice channel using selenium, ffmpeg and pydub in real time 24/7.   Most of the time i tried to run the code i got this error message:[WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.

i need to know if there is a simpler way to do this and how to do it, I'll leave a print of the code:

```
import discord
import subprocess
import asyncio

from discord.ext import commands 
from discord.flags import Intents

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, NoSuchWindowException

from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play as play_audio

#Discord bot parts

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.voice_states = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents= intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.guilds)
    print(client.user)
    print('The radio is online')

@client.event
async def on_disconnect():
    await client.close()
    print('The radio is offline')


@client.command(name='Hello')
async def ola(context):
 await context.message.channel.send('Hello!')


@client.command()
async def play(context):
    if context.author.voice is None:
        await context.send('You need to be on a channel-voice.')
        return
    
    voice_channel = context.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()

    driver_path = r'C:\Users\Athos\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe'
    options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
    driver.get('https://www.radioclube.net')

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
    play_button = await wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="player-controles"]/img[1]')))
    play_button.click()

    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    radio_url = "https://www.radioclube.net"

    
    process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i',radio_url , '-f', 's16le', '-ar', '48000', '-ac', '2', 'pipe:1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    audio_data = process.stdout.read()

    audiosegment = AudioSegment.from_raw(data=audio_data, sample_width=2, frame_rate=48000, channels=2)
    audiosegment.export("temp_audio.wav", format = "wav")


    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("temp_audio.wav", process.stdout, **ffmpeg_options))
    ffmpeg_options = { 
        'options': '-vn',
        'executable': r'C:\Users\Athos\Desktop\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe'
    }
    

    await context.send(f'Bot conectado ao canal de voz: {voice_channel.name}')
 

@client.command()
async def leave(context): 
    await context.voice_client.disconnect()
```

i also tried to use the youtube_dl library to play the audio track played on the radio in real time on discord, but this time the error is different, I run the code and enter the bot in voice but it doesn't play the radio.

```
import os
import discord
import subprocess
import asyncio
import youtube_dl

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.flags import Intents

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, NoSuchWindowException

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.voice_states = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn',
    'executable': r'C:\Users\Athos\Desktop\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe'
}

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.guilds)
    print(client.user)
    print('A Rádio está online')

@client.event
async def on_disconnect():
    await client.close()
    print('A Rádio está offline')

@client.command(name='ola')
async def ola(context):
    await context.message.channel.send('Você está conectado e ouvindo a Rádio Clube 108,9 fm!')

@client.command()
async def play(context):
    if context.author.voice is None:
        await context.send('Você precisa estar em um canal de voz para usar este comando.')
        return

    voice_channel = context.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()

    driver_path = r'C:\Users\Athos\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe'
    options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
    driver.get('https://www.radioclube.net')

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
    play_button = await wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="player-controles"]/img[1]')))
    play_button.click()

    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    radio_url = "https://www.radioclube.net"

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        'outtmpl': 'temp_audio.mp3',
        'quiet': True,
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([radio_url])

    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('temp_audio.mp3', **ffmpeg_options))

    await context.send(f'Bot conectado ao canal de voz: {voice_channel.name}')

@client.command()
async def leave(context):
    await context.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Please upload code directly into your answer instead of using images. It helps future readers to search for your content and makes the code more accessible to screen readers, among other reasons. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors